# simulating adminhtml login redirect for a bootstrap file

Tags: adminhtml, login, redirect, magento-1.4

I know that the following code detects login for a user:

```
if(!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){
    //not logged in
}else{
    // logged in
}
```

However, what is the corresponding code to determine if a user is logged in as admin?

Also, what class and method would you use to redirect to admin login, along with a post-login redirect back to a specified page?

I'm thinking you just access a different model, however I don't know which one that is.

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed very similar:

```
Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isLoggedIn()
```

But note that you cannot use this in the frontend because the `frontend` and `adminhtml` sessions are two separate sessions with different ids (you'll see that two separate cookies are stored), so only one of them can be active at a time.

> Also, what class and method would you use to redirect to admin login, along with a post-login redirect back to a specified page?

Redirect to admin login is already happening if you try to access any admin controller if you are not logged in as admin.